# C# StreamReader/StreamWriter encoding oddity

Tags: c#, character-encoding, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a very simple c# console app that reads through a text file and outputs the same file but with a particular string replaced on each line that it appears - utilizing StreamReader and StreamWriter.  I do not know the encoding of the source file. I have encountered a situation where there is a character in the file (ext ascii dec 166, broken pipe) that when running through this app gets "mangled" using the default encoding (In the output file it ends up as a "box" character).  Since I do not know the source file encoding I have attempted multiple options to see what would provide an unaltered result and oddly the only way that works is having it read in UTF-7 and written in UTF-8.

UTF-7 to UTF-7 causes problems like & to change to +AC.  UTF-8 to UTF-8 (which I believe is the default) converts the character in question to the "box".  ASCII to ASCII turns it into ?. Unicode to Unicode results in gibberish.  Shouldn't it be same encoding read and write for same results? Simplified code example below:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(fileStream,Encoding.UTF7))
using (var fileStreamOut = new FileStream(tempFileName,FileMode.Create))
using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStreamOut,Encoding.UTF8))
{                
    while (!fileReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var inputLine = fileReader.ReadLine();

        if (inputLine != null)
        {
            inputLine = inputLine.Substring(0, 3) + newRdfi + inputLine.Substring(12);
            fileWriter.WriteLine(inputLine);
        }
    }

    fileWriter.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at StreamReader.CurrentEncoding... see what that says after you've read the file.

Comment: Question 1: what happens if you try to output the file as-is, without the string substitution?  Question 2: what happens if you compare the input file against the output file using `comp` or `fc`?  (In both cases with a UTF8-to-UTF8 conversion, of course.)

Comment: StreamReader defaults to UTF-8 I believe.

Comment: CurrentEncoding is UTF-8.  I tried without string substitution and actually discovered my UTF-7 to 8 method isn't working perfectly either.  It correctly deals with the broken pipe character but it removed a + character causing one line to be a character short.

Comment: I received a e-mail response from the creator of the file they are outputting the source file using .net StreamWriter using system.text.encoding.default.

Comment: The issue here is the encoding of the *console*.  Box characters are produced in the default encoding, code page 437.  An ancient encoding that dates back to the original IBM PC.

Comment: If that's the creator's spec, then you have to use his account on his computer to read the file and only when his settings are the same as when he wrote the file. He should commit to an encoding you an agree on.

Answer (score 1):

After clarification on the file creation method received from the developer of the source system and knowledge of the server it is being produced on I came to the conclusion the encoding was Windows-1252.  Changing my read and write streams to use Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) resulted in all characters reading and outputting as expected.